# ID Calling from table

Tags: php, mysql

i have ads table and there are Id column with Int Value for thats table
and this is table save the ads thats need surf by the member
the member can surf each ad per 24hrs only
,and when the member click on surf ad button , he will surf ads DESC order by Id

EXAMPLe of the link ad Thats will show for the member

mysite com/surfing.php?area=ad&id=8

The problem if i am changed the Id Value manually from the url link(not from the the table) to any Numbers example: 5478965324

mysite com/surfing.php?area=ad&id=5478965324

and thats number not in the Id Column
but the url work and consider thats as Id

```
$id=$_GET[id];
if ($id == '') {header("location: surfing.php"); exit;}
if ($id != '0') {$ad_info=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads where id=$id"));}
if ($id == '0') {$collect=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM config"));$ad_info[link]=$collect['url'];}
if ($id == '0') {$frame1="surfing.php?area=msg&msg=1";} else {$frame1="surfing.php?area=top&&id=$id";}
if ($id == '0') {$ad_temp="<frame src='$frame1' noresize=noresize>";}
```

Comment: you need to issue a select query with the id and check its existing in the table

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '{$id}'");
```

Now check if that exists by:

```
if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1 ) 
{
   // handle error here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue a count query

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

if (is_numeric($id)) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id'");   

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

   # do your stuff

} else {

   # no rows found.


 }

}
```

PS. Usage of mysql_* functions is not recommended. Instead you can use mysqli_* of pdo functions for the same.